# Application Crashing(Any way to take print stack trace on device screen)

Tags: android

I have Two application

1-Application1   (Currently running on device)

2-Application2  (Installed on device)

what is going on exactly:-

Application1 is running fine on device.

step 1-i uninstall the Application2

step 2-i install again Application2

now if i goes to Application1 then my Application (Application1) is crashing.

is there any way to print stack Trace (Couse of crashing) on my device screen.

Comment: Look into the [ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) to print the stack trace.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse with ADT plugin, you can switch to the DDMS perspective and see the LogCat tab. You can save the logs if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install a logcat viewer such as [aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=en). 
It provides various ways for you to view, save or share the log output.

Comment: by aLogCat ,can we see couse of crashing/error's on device(like samsung tab)